# How to use while or loop statement to create a sequence of <table> automatically laravel framework

Tags: laravel

I want to create a table with foreach and while to create a table... I want to create new set of table's automatically

```
@if(count($collection) > 0)
<div class="arrg arrg_in" style="cursor: pointer;" width="100%">
    <table class="arrg_tbarrg" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            @foreach($collection as $collectios)
            @foreach($collectios->tansactions as $transaction)
            @if($transaction) 
<tr style="background-color:red">
<td> hello</td> </tr> @endif 
@endforeach 
@foreach($collectios->ptansactions as $transactio)
@if($transactio)
<tr style="background-color:red">
<td> hello people</td>
</tr>
@endif
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>

@endforeach
@endif
```

I want a completely new set of a complete table to appear...

where will I use the while statement

Comment: write proper your blade file code]

Answer (score 1):

Try Laravel's [isEmpty()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-isempty) to check if the collection is empty.

```
@if(!$collection->isEmpty())
    @foreach($collection as $collectios)   
        @foreach($collectios->tansactions as $transaction)
            @if(isset($transaction))
                write your content here
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: my question is edited... a new set of table not row

Comment: Ok @adesure Just confirming the desired workflow. For what condition do you want to create a new table? 1. `For each $transaction`, 2. `For each $collectios` or 3. `For each $collection`. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the code... i want it to create a new set of cable from the `@if(count($collection) > 0` if collection is 1... create new table...

Answer (score 0):

I guess there no need to use `while loop` here, but if you still want use `while loop` then try below code.

```
@if(!$collection->isEmpty())
    @foreach($collection as $collectios)   
        @foreach($collectios->tansactions as $transaction)
            @while(isset($transaction))
                write your content here
            @endwhile
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: what to create a new set of table automatically... not table row